# Unable to load a JSON file from google cloud storage to bigquery using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, upload, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am attempting to export a file from my Google cloud storage to Google bigquery but am running into numerous problems.

```
#standardSQL
import json
import argparse
import time
import uuid

from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import storage

dataset = 'dataworks-356fa'
source = 'gs://dataworks-356fa-backups/pullnupload.json'

def load_data_from_gcs(dataset, test10, source ):
    bigquery_client = bigquery.Client(dataset)
    dataset = bigquery_client.dataset('FirebaseArchive')
    table = dataset.table(test10)
    job_name = str(uuid.uuid4())

    job= bigquery_client.load_table_from_storage(
        job_name, table, "gs://dataworks-356fa-backups/pullnupload.json")
    job.source_format = 'NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON'
    job.begin()

    # wait_for_job(job)
    print("state of job is: " + job.state)
#     print("errors: " + job.errors)

load_data_from_gcs(dataset, 'test10', source)
```

When the `wait_for_job(job)` line is not commented out I receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "cloudtobq.py", line 42, in <module> 
load_data_from_gcs(dataset, 'test10', source) 
File "cloudtobq.py", line 38, in load_data_from_gcs 
wait_for_job(job) 
NameError: global name 'wait_for_job' is not defined
```

And when `print("errors: " + job.errors)` is not commented out I receive this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "cloudtobq.py", line 42, in <module> 
load_data_from_gcs(dataset, 'test10', source) 
File "cloudtobq.py", line 40, in load_data_from_gcs 
print("errors: " + job.errors) 
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

When both are commented out this is what I receive and then being returned to the original terminal screen.

```
Wess-MacBook-Pro:desktop wesstephens$ python cloudtobq.py
state of job is: RUNNING
Wess-MacBook-Pro:desktop wesstephens$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the definition of the function [from the documentation sample code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-post-request#bigquery-import-file-python):

```
def wait_for_job(job):
    while True:
        job.reload()
        if job.state == 'DONE':
            if job.error_result:
                raise RuntimeError(job.errors)
            return
        time.sleep(1)
```

You don't need to print `job.errors`, since `wait_for_job` will raise an exception if the job was unsuccessful.